# What is Queue in JMS

Tags: java, jms

I have a task. In parameters there are queue and message. I must send message to a queue. And I don't know where in is this queue is my queue. I think that it is Destination queue? Thanks a lot.

```
public class Producer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Получает контекст JNDI
            Context jndiContext = new InitialContext();
            // Выполняет поиск администрируемых объектов
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("jms/javaee7/ConnectionFactory" );
            Destination queue = (Destination) jndiContext.lookup("jms/javaee7/Queue");
            //Создает необходимые артефакты для соединения с очередью
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
            // Отправляет текстовое сообщение в очередь
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("Сообщение отправлено " + new Date());
            producer.send(message);
            connection.close();
        } catch (NamingException | JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your question but a queue in JMS is a Point-to-Point staging area. It ensures that messages are processed only once but it does not guarantee about order processing.

If your example you're are sending a text message to a queue `Queue` but you should do :

```
connection.start()
```

to start your connection.

Now, if you want to receive your message, you can do :

```
Context context = null;
ConnectionFactory factory = null;
Connection connection = null;
Destination destination = null;
Session session = null;
MessageConsumer receiver = null;

try {
  context = new InitialContext();
  factory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/javaee7/ConnectionFactory");
  destination = (Destination) context.lookup("jms/javaee7/Queue");
  connection = factory.createConnection();
  session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
  receiver = session.createConsumer(destination);
  connection.start();

    Message message = receiver.receive();
    if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
      TextMessage text = (TextMessage) message;
      System.out.println("received message= " + text.getText());
    } else if (message != null) {
      System.out.println("No message in queue");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (context != null) {
    try {
      context.close();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  if (connection != null) {
    try {
      connection.close();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
}
```

By the way, if you are using java 7,  you should use **The try-with-resources Statement**.